# Env Variables in NestJS not visible in every module?

Tags: nestjs

Im keeping my configuration in `.env` file when I develop my app.

This is my `app.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
      host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
      password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
      port: (process.env.TYPEORM_PORT as unknown) as number,
      type: 'postgres',
      username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    }),
    AuthModule,
    (...)
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And `typeorm` use proper values from `process.env.TYPEORM_...` variables.

This is my `auth.module.ts`:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [JwtStrategy, (...)],
  imports: [
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      (...)
    }),
    (...)
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And Im getting error from JwtModule, that `secret` can not be empty. Of course `JWT_SECRET` is set in `.env` file.

This is my `jwt.strategy.ts`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      (...)
    });
  }
  (...)
}
```

And here, `process.env.JWT_SECRET` is properly loaded.

I cant understand why my env vars are not available everywhere in my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I had to take a guess, you are calling `dotenv`'s `config()` method too late. In Typescript, decorators are run on module import, so anything in `@Module()` is run almost immediately. However, anything that is in a function call of a class method will not be run until that function is called. I'd suggest, in your `main.ts` file, having these as the first two lines:

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
```

This way, any `.env` file is read and added to `process.env` before anything else gets a chance to run.

The other option, as you are using the [`ConfigModule` provided by Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration), is to use an asynchronous registration process where you use either a factory or a class instead to provide the proper configurations. In your TypeOrm config, an async registration process could look like this:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    database: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_DATABASE'),
    host: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_HOST'),
    password: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_PASSWORD'),
    port: config.get<number>('TYPEORM_PORT'),
    type: 'postgres',
    username: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_USERNAME'),
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

For JwtModule access to env variables you can use **registerAsync**, your code should be something like this:

```
JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: config.get('JWT_SECRET_KEY'),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '1h' },
      }),
    })
```